# get category ID symfony3

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony-3.3

I've got a categories entity, and this entity has entities.

Now I want to select the blog articles that are in this category, but the category can have multiple child categories.

for example: category/books/horror/2017

Now in my controller, I allow slashes. So I can get all categories including the subcategories.

```
/**
 * @Route("/categorie/{categoryName}", name="show_category", requirements={"categoryName":".+"})
 */
 public function indexAction($categoryName)
 {    
     return new Response('<html><head></head><body>' . print_r($categoryName) . '</body></html>');
 }
```

But now I was wondering, is there a quick way to select those categories and get the right one? As the categories can be named the same!

For example:

`category/books/horror/2017`
`category/books/thriller/2017`

category is twice `2017`, but with different parent.

I was thinking of looping over the categories, and starting at books category.

So like this:

Select ID of books, then look for child horror, and look for child of horror named 2017.

But is this the best way (for this one it needs 3 queries), or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this, and can give example of code.
You need create a cool DQL.

https://gist.github.com/MaximStrutinskiy/249179e14fe6a90673f0f3e4dc931d31

Maybe it's help or will prompt the way to solve the problem